# jQuery data access from html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have

```
<div data-text="This is a text">...</div>
```

I need to access the data-text in javascript.
It works with `alert($('div').data('text'));` but not with `alert($.data($('div'), 'text'));` gives me undefined.

WHY?

LINK: http://jsfiddle.net/tvDzP/2/

(For performance issues I use `element.attr('data-text')` to retrieve the text )

Comment: please post example of non-working code. Maybe $ is not defined (jQuery run in non-conflict mode)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally `$.data` expects a DOM node, not a jQuery object.

```
$('div').data('text') // correct
$.data($('div')[0], 'text') // correct
$.data($('div'), 'text') // incorrect
```

However, for the `data-*` attributes, `$.data` doesn't work unless the value has already been retreived once by `$(element).data()`.

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/):

> **Regarding HTML5 data-* attributes:** This low-level method does NOT retrieve the `data-*` attributes unless the more convenient `.data()` method has already retrieved them.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sErZF/)

Answer (score 0):

`element` has to be a DOM element, not a selector or a jQuery object:

```
$.data($('div')[0], 'text')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CGck6/